# How to get node without children in xQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic

So I have two nodes of elements that I'm essentially trying to join. I want the top level node to stay the same but the child nodes to be replaced by those cross referenced.

Given:

```
<stuff>
  <item foo="foo" boo="1"/>
  <item foo="bar" boo="2" />
  <item foo="baz" boo="3"/>
  <item foo="blah boo="4""/>
</stuff>

<list  a="1" b="2">
  <foo>bar</foo>
  <foo>baz</foo>
</list>
```

I want to loop through "list" and cross reference elements in "stuff" for this result:

```
<list  a="1" b="2">
  <item foo="bar" boo="2" />
  <item foo="baz" boo="3"/>  
</list>
```

I want to do this without having to know about what attributes might be on "list". In other words I don't want to have to explicitly call them out like

```
attribute a { $list/@a }, attribute b { $list/@b }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use:**

**`$list1/item[@foo = $list2/item/@foo]`**

This selects all `<item>` elements in `$list1` the value of whose `foo` attribute is equal to the `foo` attribute of one of the `<item>` elements in $list2.

**In order to copy all attributes of the `<list>` element, do something like this**:

```
  for $attr in /whateverIsthePathLeadingToList/list/@*
    return 
      attibute {name($attr)} {$attr}
```

Comment: for $list in //list
return
The @* was the big piece I was missing

<list>{ $list/@* ,
   OTHER STUFF
}
</list>

Comment: what is list1 and list2?

Comment: `$list1` is a variable that holds the element whose children have to be copied in the result -- in this particular case `$list1` will hold the `<stuff>` element.

`$list2` is a variable that holds the element, whose children-elements are the "filters" -- in this particular case `$list2` will hold the `<list>` element.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly simplier ... to create a new  object from an existing one, but without its children only attributes

assume :

let $old_list :=

This creates a new list copying its attributes

```
 <list>{$old_list/@*}</list>
```